# Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by

Tags: php

I've a php script the first thing in the code is `session_start();`, but I keep receiving this error

`Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/****/public_html/admincp/index.php:1) in /home/****/public_html/admincp/index.php on line 1`

but the script works great in the `localhost`.

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php
require 'global.php';
?>


<?php

//check if the user logged in
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
page_redirect('login.php'); // go to login.php.
?>
```

Comment: If you’re using UTF-8, check your file for the byte-order mark (BOM) and remove it.

Comment: @meze the error on the line 1 not in the middle of the script. I have knowledge about making the session start in the beginning of the script.

Comment: @Othman the answer there has explanations for all cases, even if it happens on the first line.

Comment: I've tried everything, still not working any help please :(

Comment: did you really try the answer from Gumbo? I also had once a problem with session_start and headers already sent... my source was saved as UTF8 "with BOM" (this  is a invisible character in front of the document, but visible for php).. save it without bom and it should work.

Comment: @qxxx how I can access these invisible characters I'm searching the web now to find something.

Comment: in your text editor there should be a function for this, in notepad++ for example in menu "Encoding / Convert to UTF8 without BOM" - some editors have this function in the save dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Open the file in your favorite text editor and convert the file to UTF8 without BOM.
Annoying error, once did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times a lone whitespace character at the top of the file can cause this error, because the whitespace character gets output. Make sure that there's nothing above that `<?php session_start(); ?>`, not even a whitespace character. If the host you're on has an auto_prepend_file, that could also throw it off.

Comment: as you can see there is no any white spaces, and the error on line 1

Comment: Then add this line at the very top of the file, and see if it fixes it: `<?php ob_clean(); ?>`

Comment: same error, but in line 2 now

Comment: okay, try this then: <?php ob_clean();session_start();?> if that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: still the same in line 1